# gorm multiple databases connection management

Tags: go, go-gorm, golang-migrate

I have a requirement where my application talks to different
databases . How do i manage connections in the gorm.  Is there any
way gorm supports connection management for multiple database. or i
need to create  map which holds all database connections.

```
if val, ok := selector.issure_db[issuer]; ok {
    return val , nil;

} else {

    var dbo  *db.DB;

    selector.mu.Lock()

    dbo, err := db.NewDb(Config)

    if err != nil {
        boot.Logger(ctx).Fatal(err.Error())
    }

    selector.issure_db[issuer] = dbo;

    selector.mu.Unlock()

    return repo ,nil;
}
```

Is there is a better way to do this?

Comment: What about creating all DB at bootstrap time?

Comment: my databases might grow depending on the clients.

Comment: You should use a factory function to get DB, it'll have mutex and other stuff.

Comment: is there factory support in gorm?

Comment: Not something I'm aware of you can build one as you have done with selector map.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a package called database and write an init function in the init.go file which can create a DB object to connect with database for each database you have. And you can use this db object everywhere in the application which would enable connection pooling as well.

init.go

```
var db *gorm.DB

func init() {
    var err error
    dataSourceName := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@tcp(%s:%d)/%s?charset=utf8&parseTime=True&loc=Local", dbUser, dbPassword, dbHost, dbPort, dbName)
    db, err = gorm.Open("mysql", dataSourceName)
    db.DB().SetConnMaxLifetime(10 * time.Second)
    db.DB().SetMaxIdleConns(10)

    //initialise other db objects here
}
```

users.go

```
func getFirstUser() (user User) {
    db.First(&user)
    return
}
```

PS> This solution would be efficient if you have to connect to 1 or 2 database. If you need to connect to multiple databases at the same time, you should be using dbresolver plugin.

**Old Answer**

You can write a separate function which returns current database connection object every time you call the function.

```
func getDBConnection(dbUser, dbPassword, dbHost, dbName string) (db *gorm.DB, err error) {
    dataSourceName := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@tcp(%s:%d)/%s?charset=utf8&parseTime=True&loc=Local", dbUser, dbPassword, dbHost, dbPort, dbName)
    db, err = gorm.Open("mysql", dataSourceName)
    db.DB().SetConnMaxLifetime(10 * time.Second)
    return
}
```

And call defer db.Close() everytime after you call the getDBConnection function.

```
func getFirstUser() (user User) {
    db, _ := getDBConnection()
    defer db.Close()
    db.First(&user)
    return
}
```

This way your connections will be closed every time after you have executed the query.

Comment: Are you sure this would work performance wise? Imagine trying to handle e.g 1000 simultaneous users and you open and close 1000 times the database connection.

Comment: Yes, here `gorm.Open` doesn't open a new connection every time you call getDBConnection. In fact, `gorm.Open` internally uses database/sql package which handles connection pooling for you.

Comment: From the documentation, in order for gorm to reuse the connection you need to pass an existing db connection https://gorm.io/docs/connecting_to_the_database.html#Existing-database-connection and not a DSN. How would it know in this case that it needs to keep it as a connection pool and not a simple open / close?

Comment: Thanks for correcting. I have updated my answer which would just create one DB object and reuse the same DB object in the entire application and also enable connection pooling.

Comment: Your code still doesn't make much sense mate, you have a globally defined db variable, everytime you would call init with the new connection string (missing in the function definition) if would overwrite the other connection getting you back to square 1. You could solve this with a map of db objects

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [dbresolver](https://github.com/go-gorm/dbresolver) plugin for GORM. It manages multiple sources and replicas and maintains an underlying connection pool for the group. You can even map models in your app to the correct database using the config.

Example from the docs:

```
import (
  "gorm.io/gorm"
  "gorm.io/plugin/dbresolver"
  "gorm.io/driver/mysql"
)

db, err := gorm.Open(mysql.Open("db1_dsn"), &gorm.Config{})

db.Use(dbresolver.Register(dbresolver.Config{
  // use `db2` as sources, `db3`, `db4` as replicas
  Sources:  []gorm.Dialector{mysql.Open("db2_dsn")},
  Replicas: []gorm.Dialector{mysql.Open("db3_dsn"), mysql.Open("db4_dsn")},
  // sources/replicas load balancing policy
  Policy: dbresolver.RandomPolicy{},
}).Register(dbresolver.Config{
  // use `db1` as sources (DB's default connection), `db5` as replicas for `User`, `Address`
  Replicas: []gorm.Dialector{mysql.Open("db5_dsn")},
}, &User{}, &Address{}).Register(dbresolver.Config{
  // use `db6`, `db7` as sources, `db8` as replicas for `orders`, `Product`
  Sources:  []gorm.Dialector{mysql.Open("db6_dsn"), mysql.Open("db7_dsn")},
  Replicas: []gorm.Dialector{mysql.Open("db8_dsn")},
}, "orders", &Product{}, "secondary"))
```